# Not able to calculate in C.How do you calculate in C?

Tags: c, math, expression

Im new to C and I really don't know know what I'm doing wrong.

The issue that I am having is I'm supposed to ask 3 questions of the user using scanf. I'm supposed to ask the user for an integer, a positive real number and a non negative number and then calculate the numbers into `XX.XX` using `%.2f`.

```
                    //pre-processor directives


 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>



                    //main function
int main()

{
 //declare variables
int smp1,smp2, smp3,total;


printf("sample 1?\n");  // positive integer
scanf("%d", &smp1);


printf("sample 2?\n");  //positive real number
scanf("%f",&smp2);


printf("sample 3?\n");  // non negative number
scanf("%u", &smp3);


total = (smp1 + smp2 / smp3);              
printf("The final result is %.2f",total);

                        //end of main
    return 0;
 }
```

No matter what I put in there my result ends up being `0.00`. It won't even do simple addition and I don't know enough to know why.

Comment: You should learn about types and how they correspond to `scanf` format  specifiers.

Comment: Does your code compile with no warnings?

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! You need to declare `total` and `smp2` as float. Otherwise, you get garbage and integer division !

Comment: I wouldn't read a "real number" into an `int`. A real number is probably better stored as `float` or `double`. Otherwise, you will lose any input after decimal point. (and `scanf("%f");` will do terrible things...)

Comment: Chris,No warnings.The code runs,it just doesn't work.

Comment: You need to turn up your warning level, then.

Comment: There is enough wrong in this code to warrant a revisit to whatever book, tutorial, or lecture, you're learning from. You're lying to `scanf` by not providing the the proper arguments to the format specifiers you're providing in the second and third cases. You're lying to `printf` by doing the same thing. And it is entirely possible you're unfamiliar with integer-division concepts in C (which truncates remainders).

Comment: Some compilers don't warn about `printf` and `scanf` parameters whose types do not match their corresponding conversion specifiers in the format string, so increasing the warning level might not help. Even so, you should consult the documentation for those functions.

Comment: @IanAbbott That's true, but: It's abundantly clear from the questions we get every day that there are lots of C learners who imagine they ought to be able to type in anything that occurs to them, and it ought to either work as they expect, or give them an error message.  So compilers that *do* warn (by default) about printf and scanf format specifier type mismatch are an absolutely mandatory part of that worldview.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that you declare all your variables as `int`s, but `smp2` and `total` must hold floating point values.

Change your declarations to

```
int smp1;
double smp2, total;
unsigned int smp3;
```

This way, the types of the variables match up with the conversion specifiers used in the `printf` and `scanf` calls.

Types matter in C, and it's up to you that the types of the arguments in each `printf` and `scanf` call match up with the conversion specifiers.

Check your compiler documentation on how to enable warnings (even better, to treat all warnings as errors).  Most compilers *should* warn about type mismatches like this, but sometimes you have to set a flag in order for those warnings to appear.